# Laravel4 Pagination not working after upgrade to PHP5.6

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a working pagination code on my machine using PHP5.4
After upgrading to PHP5.6 the pagination stays on the first page. When i clicked on the next page, the address bar show the page number (i.e: http://mysite/page?page=4). However, the button still on page 1.
The same code still working on my Windows (WAMP) using PHP5.5.
Fyi, im using Freebsd 9.1, Nginx, PHP5.6 (upgraded)
Is there something to do with PHP itself, or am i missing some extensions?

Found extra information,
I have installed laravel logviewer package on this app. The pagination that come with this package also didn't works. 
I suspect that, this is nothing to do with code. Maybe php or nginx config.

Comment: Debug? Any error log?

Comment: No error. Page is fine. But the pagination didn't work.

Comment: With `Page is fine`, you mean: you see the content of page 2 but the active pagination is still on page 1?

Comment: no, its page 1. navigation button is there, with correct numbers. but when clicked, it redirects to the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally figured it out.
it's true about nginx rewrite.
my previous setting in vhost file is:
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;

i changed to
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

this problem is clearly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please check php (apache) configuration and check if required modules activated

Comment: don't know where else to look. everything runs except this.

Comment: Use phpinfo();   and check if all required modules are activated or not

Comment: do you mean required modules to run laravel 4?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, 
I finally solved this.
However, i didn't find the cause yet.

Originally, my pagination code is like this:
{{ $data->links() }}

When i use append() in the pagination, it works.
{{ $data->appends(array('filter1' => $var1))->links() }}

I suspect this is something to do with nginx rewrite.